# Is there a name for the decomposition of $m^1w^1-m^0w^0$ into $(m^1-m^0)w^0+(w^1-w^0)m^0+(m^1-m^0)(w^1-w^0)$?

Tags: terminology, factoring

In the following, what is this kind of decomposition / factoring called? I'd like to read the proof for it or learn more:

$$m^1w^1-m^0w^0=(m^1-m^0)w^0+(w^1-w^0)m^0+(m^1-m^0)(w^1-w^0)$$

It doesn't appear to be a [factoring of a trinomial](https://www.montereyinstitute.org/courses/DevelopmentalMath/COURSE_TEXT2_RESOURCE/U12_L2_T1_text_final.html), so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: What if it doesn't have a special name?

Comment: Oh! Weird. @MJD

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure it has a name, but intuitively it is

- on the left hand side the big rectangle minus the green rectangle
- on the right hand side the sum of the three pink rectangles

[image]